# Can the Worklight AppCenter use custom provisioning?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-appcenter

Worklight 6.2 on Liberty

Can I configure the AppCenter to use custom provisioning outlined in the GettingStarted material?

The server/conf folder is present in the AppCenter project, so it seems I could configure custom provisioning and build the war. The questions seem to be, will the appcenter client
access the new appcenter war like a normal worklight client with respect to the security mechanism, and will the new appcenter war respond like a normal worklight server to those requests?

Answer (score 1):

No, IBM Worklight Application Center does not support the Worklight custom provisioning. The IBM Worklight Application Center server is no Worklight server (in the sense that it does not derive from the Worklight server classes).

The custom provisioning mechanism is often used to restrict the mobile devices that can connect to the Worklight server. However, for AppCenter, any device that runs the AppCenter client can connect to the server with a correct user and password. If restrictions are needed, they should be implemented in the mobile app, not in the facility that installs the mobile app.